# Plotting relative time series from the rows of a pandas data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where each row contains a relative time series, along with some columns of relevant data. Something like this:

```
    id group  treatment  1  2  3   4   5  ...  2701
0  001     A    control  1  2  3   4   5  ...   150
1  002     A  high_dose  1  1  4   7  49  ...    28
2  003     A   low_dose  1  2  4   9  80  ...   200
3  004     B    control  1  3  5   8  36  ...   476
4  005     B  high_dose  1  5  5  12  27  ...   789
5  006     B   low_dose  1  4  9  36   8  ...    12
```

Where the columns labeled '1','2','3',...'270'1 are measurements collected every second for 45 minutes. I would like to the time series for each 'id', but I would also like to be able to color code the lines using other variables such as "group" or "dose". I have plotted the time series by transposing the data frame and creating a timedelta index. However, I had to drop the other columns(group and dose) to do this. Is there a clean way to plot the time series and be able to keep the other columns to use for color coding the plots (e.g. as a hue parameter in Seaborn)? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share with us what you've done so far.